# How to pass regex as an argument to subroutine in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Probably I'm doing something totally wrong, but is there some way to modify and combine `regexes` using subroutines? The program below wouldn't compile.

```perl6
sub a(Regex $r1) {
  return rx/ <$r1> a /
}

my regex letter_b { b };

my $new = a(letter_b);
say $new;
```

Comment: FYI, there's no need to write `<$r1>` given that raku already knows `$r1` is a `Regex`. That is to say, you could just write `sub a(Regex $r1) { return rx/ $r1 a / }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`Regex`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Regex), it says:

> A named `regex` can be defined with the regex declarator followed by its definition in curly braces. Since any regex does `Callable` introspection requires referencing via `&`-sigil.
>
> ```
> my regex R { \N };
> say &R.^name; # OUTPUT: «Regex␤»
> ```

Also, the [`Grammar`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars) documentation (for the concept, not the Type), it explains more about this:

> The main ingredient of grammars is named regexes. While the syntax of Perl 6 Regexes is outside the scope of this document, *named* regexes have a special syntax, similar to subroutine definitions:
>
> ```
> my regex number { \d+ [ \. \d+ ]? }
> ```
>
> In this case, we have to specify that the regex is lexically scoped using the `my` keyword, because named regexes are normally used within grammars.
>
> Being named gives us the advantage of being able to easily reuse the regex elsewhere:
>
> ```
> say so "32.51" ~~ &number;                                    # OUTPUT: «True␤»
> say so "15 + 4.5" ~~ / <number> \s* '+' \s* <number> /        # OUTPUT: «True␤»
> ```

So, to pass your named regex as a parameter into your `a` subroutine, all you have to do is prefix it with an ampersand:

```
my $new = a(&letter_b);
#           ^
#  This is what you need!

say $new;
say so "ba" ~~ $new;         # OUTPUT: «True␤»
say so "ca" ~~ $new;         # OUTPUT: «False␤»
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting with @callyalater's conclusion<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
my $new = a(&letter_b);
#           ^
#  This is what you need!
```

In the rest of this answer I address two follow on questions I imagine folk might still have if @callyalater's answer doesn't work for them.

- Why?
- What's with the error message?

## Why?

Almost all programming languages have named functions you can declare once and then call any number of times. Many support [functions as first class values](https://www.google.com/search?q=functions+as+first+class+values). Raku does. This means raku allows you to refer to an already declared function in two fundamentally distinct ways:

- To ["call" a function](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22call+a+function%22), write its name. It will actively do what it's declared to do.
- To just "refer" to a function as a first class value, prepend a `&`. The reference will be passively passed on.

Thus:

```
sub foo { say 42 }
say foo; # 42
say &foo # &foo
```

Before I can continue, I must note that things get slightly tricky when writing about these things in English or whatever human language. First, by definition in English, if we write *anything* then we're referring to it! Also, one can't actually "call" `foo` in English. So the convention is to write just `foo` when it should be obvious by context whether we mean calling it (in raku, `foo`) or merely "referring" to it (in raku, `&foo`).

Unlike other languages, in raku regexes are functions. In the second line of the following code, `letter_b` is being *called*, not merely referred to:

```
my regex letter_b { b }
letter_b
```

So in `my $new = a(letter_b);`, the regex `letter_b` is being *called*, and *the result of that call* would be passed to the call of `a`, whereas in `my $new = a(&letter_b);`, you're merely passing *a reference to* `letter_b`.

## What's with the error message?

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 0␤
```

There are several classes of functions in raku. One is [`Regex`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Regex). The `Regex` class is a sub-class of [`Method`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Method):

```
my regex foo { ... }
say &foo ~~ Method; # True
my method bar { ... }
say &bar ~~ Method; # True
```

What happens if you call the method `bar` without an invocant?:

```
bar # Too few positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 0
```

That's why you get that error message if you call `letter_b` without an argument/invocant.

(If you declare a method in a grammar, it automatically gets the grammar class/object as its invocant; remember that grammars are classes.)

## Footnotes

<sup>[1]</sup> I often review an answer of mine if someone upvotes it long after I wrote it. Someone just did. If I see a way to improve the collective usefulness of our comments/answers, eg by deleting or editing my question, I do so, sometimes by rewriting it to work as a comment relative to the accepted answer.

Comment: The more I learn about Perl 6, the more I become convinced that it can do absolutely everything! :) Thanks especially for the explanation on calling `r1` syntax!

Comment: And yes, the compiler's complaint was exactly what you say — `Too few positionals`.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Thanks. I'm glad you're enjoying P6. :)